# Returing NULL when trying to access data from a data frame within a list

Tags: r, list, null, dataframe

I am trying to create two vectors of latitude (variable lat) and longitude (variable lon) from the tracks data frame within the list.  I am using the readGPX function to access data from my Garmin 500.  Here is my code:

```
library(plotKML)

data <- readGPX("C:/Users/Ryan Caldwell/Documents/activity_273464208.gpx")

a <- data[4]
b <- a$lon
c <- a$lat
```

Here are the results if I ask for the string of data:

```
str(data)
List of 5
 $ metadata : NULL
 $ bounds   : NULL
 $ waypoints: NULL
 $ tracks   :List of 1
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ Untitled:'data.frame': 919 obs. of  5 variables:
  .. .. ..$ lon       : num [1:919] -87.5 -87.5 -87.5 -87.5 -87.5 ...
  .. .. ..$ lat       : num [1:919] 38 38 38 38 38 ...
  .. .. ..$ ele       : chr [1:919] "127.0" "127.0" "127.0" "127.0" ...
  .. .. ..$ time      : chr [1:919] "2013-02-14T13:47:02.000Z" "2013-02-14T13:47:06.000Z" "2013-02-14T13:47:11.000Z" "2013-02-14T13:47:16.000Z" ...
  .. .. ..$ extensions: chr [1:919] "16.010920" "16.011164" "16.011572" "16.01160" ...
 $ routes   : NULL
```

The result I get for the string of the variable b is:

```
str(b)
 NULL
```

Why am I getting Null as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` does not have an element named `lat` or `long` -- they are buried within the `tracks` variable. I think the following should work:

```
b <- a$tracks[[1]][[1]]$lon
c <- a$tracks[[1]][[1]]$lat
```